# How to Set Locale for Aspose.word

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I'm having locale issues while using Aspose to generate PDF files based on a word template.
Aspose is formatting the numbers based on the system locale (usually English US on our system), but I need it to always be formatted in French FR.

Is there a way to set and "lock" the locale configuration in either Aspose or Word to French and ignore the system locale?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can specify culture for a thread and run Aspose.Words conversion in this thread.

```cs
CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
// Change current culture.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
try
{
    // Generate your document here.
}
finally
{
    // Restore culture.
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

Comment: Do you use mail merge to fill template with data? If so, please share sample data and marge field code. For testing I put mergefield with date format like this { MERGEFIELD test \@ "MMMM d" }, filled it using Aspose.Words mail merge feature and in the resulting document get "avril 23" value, that seems to be correct (French).